# Using a custom library inside of a custom library in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, libraries

the problem I am having is that I am trying to use a custom library inside of another custom library I made within codeigniter. They are both in the libraries folder and CodeIgniter tells me that I have to first load the instance of CI which I did...

```
class MyClass {

public function __construct()
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->load->library("OtherClass");
}
```

Now inside of a function within this class I am trying to use my other library..

```
public function my_function()
{
      $CI->otherclass->function_inside_this_class();
}
```

The error I am getting is

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined variable: CI
Filename: libraries/MyClass.php
Line Number: 20
```

Is there something I am missing in terms of declaring the codeigniter instance itself?

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your CI variable scope is limited to the constructor function at the moment. You can make a class variable that has class scope and will be accessible via `$this->variable` in all functions within that class.

```
class MyClass {

private $_CI; // make a private class variable here. 

public function __construct()
{
    $this->_CI =& get_instance();
    $this->_CI->load->library("OtherClass");
}
public function my_function()
{
    $this->_CI->otherclass->function_inside_this_class();
}
```

Comment: Is the underscore required? also what if I made the variable public? Would that implement security flaws?

Comment: The underscore is not required, sorry forgot to mention it. It's just convention that i use for private variables. It's better to have this as a private variable as it doesn't make sense for this to be accessed outside this class.

Comment: @user1296953 No, the underscore is not required, and there shouldn't be any security problems (if they needed to, they could call `get_instance`) if it is private, but the idea is that only the class needs the variable, it's not for public use.

Answer (score 0):

I think you shouldn't use CI. Include the `second_library.php` and create a new class in `first_library.php`. Or isn't possible?